# Vector space basis in a commutative diagram

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

[image]

Given the vector spaces $V,V',W,W'$ of different dimensions and maps $g,g',f_0,f_1$ in the commutative diagram above, what is the basis of the cokernels $W/im(g)$ and $W'/im(g')$?

The dimensions are simply $$dim(W/im(g)) = dim(W) -dim(im(g))$$ and $$dim(W'/im(g')) = dim(W') - dim(im(g'))$$

Is there any way to state anything more about these spaces? I was wondering if the dimensions may be equal, since the diagram is commutative, but I haven't been able to prove it.

EDIT:
Letting $$g = \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0 & 0  \\
   0       & 1 & 0 \\
    0       & 0& 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$f_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0 & 0  \\
   0       & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0& 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$f_0 = \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0 & 0  \\
   0       & 1 & 0 \\
    0       & 0& 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$g' = \begin{bmatrix}
    1      & 0 & 0  \\
   0       & 0 & 0 \\
    0       & 0& 0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Gives

\begin{align}
&W\im(g) = span{\begin{bmatrix}
    0  \\
   0   \\
    1   
\end{bmatrix}} \\
&W'\im(g') = span{\begin{bmatrix}
    0  \\
   1   \\
    0   
\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
    0  \\
   0   \\
    1   
\end{bmatrix}}
\end{align}

So the dimensions are not always equal. In this case $f_1 = g'$ which forces $f_2$ to be the zero map. There are however cases where $f_1 != g'$ and $f_2$ is a matrix. I am unsure how to make any more general statements about the diagram than this.

Comment: Besides trying to prove equality of those dimensions, did you also attempt to disprove equality by constructing a counterexample? If so what happened in that attempt?

Comment: What do you mean by *the* basis?

Answer (score 1):

Take your preferred linear map $f_1\colon W\to W'$. No constraints whatsoever on it.

Now take $V=V'=\{0\}$, so you can uniquely fill in a commutative diagram as in your picture and $f_2$ will be the same as $f_1$, that is, completely arbitrary.

So no general statement can be done about the *horizontal* arrows; the standard rank-nullity theorem holds for the *vertical* arrows, as you noticed.

For other situations, there's nothing that prevents $g'$ from being surjective, forcing $W'/\operatorname{im}(g)=\{0\}$. Here $W/\operatorname{im}(g)$ could be anything at all.